# how i can get attribute request in service symofny 6

Tags: symfony

I defined apiVersion globally in for every endpoints.

```
#config/routes/annotations.yaml

controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix: api/v{apiVersion}
    requirements:
        apiVersion: '1|2'
    defaults:
        apiVersion: 1
```

and want to have it as parameters in service

```
#config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.apiVersion: ?????
```

What i am trying to get attribute from request and defined it global as parameters in service.

Comment: Could you may provide some code?

Comment: I think you might be going about this backwards.  Your api version is probably the sort of thing that goes in an env file and then you use the ENV syntax to add to your config files.  Details are in the docs.

Comment: so for example, i have a service with multi version and want to know which version are you trying to call .
www.example.com/api/v1/test
www.example.com/api/v2/test
and i want to know globally (in service parameters) the api version is calling